# Website Analytics - haveamint.com or Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is there a comparative analysis available for [Mint](http://haveamint.com) and Google Analytics which can help me decide which one to implement in my situation?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you want to implement?

Comment: i wanted to implement analytics on on my product website and need to evaluate the pros & cons of mint & GA

Comment: I run both on my personal website. I check Mint daily sometimes multiple times per day to see what is getting read recently. I check Google Analytics far less frequently. Google Analytics is very popular and good to learn, but I like Mint.

Answer (score 9):

For every website I work on I only use Google Analytics. My main reasons:

- free -- for unlimited sites and hits
- no ads
- I don't find it hard to use and my clients haven't found it hard either (most figure it out within minutes)
- it has an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/), so if you want more, you can add your own stats or even incorporate into the site
- for ecommerce, the extra tracking for ecommerce is great
- there are theories that it might even help your Google ranking (as they gain extra data about your site)
- a lot of people use it, so often the JS is cached
- easy to setup (I don't know about mint, but GA is a few lines of JS)
- connects to adsense so the stats can be tracked together (I don't know if others support this)

... and more.

Comment: Actually if you go over (I believe) a billion hits a month, you have to switch to Google Analytics Platinum. Of course few websites are that popular, you get some other features with Google Analytics Platinum such as more custom tracking variables.

Answer (score 2):

Mint is simpler, always up to date, and has a lot of plugins aimed at blogs and personal sites. Google Analytics is more complicated and takes a little time to understand, is updated daily, and has more features for larger sites such as marketing, e-commerce and such.

On my own sites I started with Mint, used both of them for a while, but now I'm pretty happy with just Google Analytics.

Comment: what was the deciding factor which moved you to GA completely ?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Google Analytics in an enterprise environment for a few years now. There are certainly limitations, in particular with merging to other datasets. The API has been invaluable to bridging this gap, and really encouraging stakeholders to ask better questions.

In my opinion, evaluate both and work out the strengths and weaknesses based on your business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you opted for these two possible options in particular?  There are a number of good packages out there, many of which are free and offer excellent services that may provide compelling advantages over the "default" choice, Google.

Have a look at [this ReadWriteWeb](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/10_web_analytics_tools_free_innovative.php) post that compares 10 free analytics tools for starters.

I use [Clicky](http://getclicky.com) on my site and find it to be an excellent alternative to GA.

Comment: Clicky looks good, just to bad you have choose between ads and paying :(

Comment: The ads aren't really that imposing - just two small banners at the top of the page.  Given that you're more concerned with the actual metrics and trend charts, you tend not to notice them at all for focussing on the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in open source server-side analytics you should check http://piwik.org/. I did not use it myself but I've heard good it's decent, comparable to Google Analytics. I myself use GA and I'm happy with it. Just get some additional testing like Kiss Metrics and you should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend GA so that as your site grows bigger, you are already on top of a fine analytics tool. Mint is fine for now, but you need to plan for the future, too.