# What is the best web log analysis software?

Tags: logging, browser, web

We are currently using SurfStats and I am trialling Sawmill at the moment as a possible replacement as it does not require the code injection that Google Analytics does.

Is there a better package available or is it better to inject your own code (website is ASP.Net - VS2003) and write your own analysis application? Has anyone had any experience of doing this?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding [Sawmill](http://www.sawmill.net/) to be very good indeed! Though expensive.

Answer (score 1):

take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844684/website-analytics-haveamint-com-or-google-analytics) at a similar question from me where a lot of people have given several different options

Comment: Thanks, done that. Seems everyone raves about GA but anything that means we have to chnage the site code means we hit testing bottelnecks due to the security implications - we are a gov site.

Answer (score 0):

Microsofts [logparser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) is pretty good.

Jeff Atwood describes it [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000369.html)